# How to get the path of an .ear file in application server?

Tags: java, jboss, websphere, ear

I use JBoss 7.0 and WebSphere 8.5 application servers to deploy my `.ear` file which has `.war`s and EJB `.jar`s.

How to get my `.ear` file path using Java eg. `jboss7.0/standalone/deployments/sample.ear`? If needed, I can use a separate Java servlet class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a war file you can call ServetContext.getRealPath("/") which will give you the file system path to the war file. The war should be in the ear. This of course assumes that these are expanded as directories and not .war/.ear files (getRealPath only returns a non-null path in the former case).